# universal image loader out of memory

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, universal-image-loader

I get OOM error when the screen of more than 10 images at a time. 
My configs:

```
       DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .cacheInMemory(false)
            .build();

ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this)
            .diskCacheSize(500 * 1024 * 1024)
            .threadPoolSize(5)
            .build();
```

Comment: Try reducing the bitmap.

Comment: I came to the conclusion that it is necessary to create previews. please tell me, how to set two directories to cache. For previews and for full size?

Comment: Ok. Configs It is singleton. I can't create previews from the specifics of the library.  leaks can not be. It is fail?